# Running a notebook which imports and exports files repeatedly

Tags: export, import, files-and-directories, automation, iteration

I am trying to automate the process of running a Mathematica notebook that takes as an input a .txt file and exports another .txt file. This notebook was not written by me, and I don't fully understand its inner workings, but I think all I need to know is the following parts of the code:

The input statement is:

```
my_input_file = Import["my_file_name.txt", "Table"];
```

The export statement is:

```
Export["exported_file_name.txt", my_input_file_transformed, "Table"]
```

I would like to run notebook for many (100) different `my_file_name.txt` files which I could name however I want to facilitate the import process, e.g. `my_file_name_1.txt`, `my_file_name_2.txt`, etc., and put them in the same folder as the `my_mathematica_notebook.nb`.

Similarly, I would like to save the 100 different exported .txt files, in the same form I input them in order to be able to reconcile each imported-exported pair of files, e.g. something like `exported_file_name_1.txt`, `exported_file_name_2.txt`

I guess my question is how to run the notebook many times for similarly named files and how to export the files as described above. I have read answers on related questions that call a notebook from another notebook, but none that automates the import of .txt files.

My knowledge of Mathematica is very basic, especially that related to file management, so I am unable to translate the answers I found into a solution for my problem. If it helps, I am working on a Linux machine and could use the command line to automate the process if needed.

Any help with this would be very appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: `my_input_file` is not a valid Wolfram Language identifier.

Comment: Could you give an example of a valid one? Thanks for the edits by the way.

Comment: `myInputFile` would be valid. Wolfram Language supports camel-case, but not snake-case. `myInputFile` is parsed as `Times[Blank[file], Pattern[my, Blank[input]]]`

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing all of the details, I suggest using an additional Notebook to automate the operation of "my_mathematica_notebook.nb"

In the new Notebook

```
    names = FileNames["*.txt", {".", "*"}, 1]
    num = Dimensions[names][[1]]
    (* finds all txt files *)

    process[index_]:=Module[{}
    CopyFile[names[[index]],"my_file_name.txt"];
    (* copy the file to the placeholder filename *)
    NotebookEvaluate["my_mathematica_notebook.nb", InsertResults -> False];
    (* Run the Notebook *)
    CopyFile["exported_file_name.txt",StringJoin["exported",names[[index]]]];
    (* Copy the default export to the desired filename *)
    ]

    (* "loop over" all txt files located *)
    Table[process[indx],{indx,1,num,1}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly what I was looking for. I am getting an error `Module::argmu: Module called with 1 argument; 2 or more arguments are expected.` It points to just inside the square bracket after  `(* Copy the default export to the desired filename *)`

Comment: Add comma after `{}` in `Module`: `Module[{}, CopyFile ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure functions will be helpful here.  Start by using `Table` to automatically create the 100 files names you plan on entering.

```
importnames=Table[StringJoin["my_file_name_", ToString[i], ".txt"], {i, 1, 100}]
```

Since this will all be text, you can Import them all at once and keep them in a single variable to alter later.

```
imported=Import[#]&/@importnames
```

Now you can manipulate your text.  Let's pretend you want it all upper case.

```
manipulated=ToUpperCase/@imported
```

Next create all your export names in the same manner as above.

```
exportnames=Table[StringJoin["exported_file_name_", ToString[i], ".txt"], {i, 1, 100}]
```

An easy way to automate the export process is create a list of lists where each entry contains the export name and the file contents.  You can do that with `Transpose`.

```
exportdata=Transpose[{exportnames,manipulated}]
```

Then run all the exports at the same time.

```
Export[#[[1]],#[[2]]]&/@exportdata
```

If you aren't familiar with slots and mapping, you can read up on [Pure Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very instructive. However, it does not include how to run `my_mathematica_notebook.nb` right?

Comment: @Ouroboroski Simply evaluate the cells.